# psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "test" Getting error when moving code to test server

Tags: python, django

I'm running Django 1.11 with Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Moving my development code to the test server and running into some strange errors.  Can anyone see what is wrong from the traceback?

I'm very new to linux and have made the mistake of developing on a Windows machine on this first go around.  I have since created a virtualbox copy of the test and production servers to develop on, but I'm hoping I can salvage what's up on the test server now.

I think my app is looking in the correct directory for this environment, but I am a Django, Python and linux noob.

Any direction would be very helpful.

**UPDATE: I added models.py and migration for relevant app. Also, I was using sqlite on dev machine and am using postgreSQL on test server (like a fool).

Thanks! 
staff_manager/models.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Create your models here.

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from smrt.settings import DATE_INPUT_FORMATS


class OrganizationTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.organization_title_name)
    organization_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class ClassificationTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.classification_title_name)
    classification_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class WorkingTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.working_title_name)
    working_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.category_name)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Department(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.department_name)
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    org_title = models.ForeignKey(OrganizationTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    manager_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    classification_title = models.ForeignKey(ClassificationTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    working_title = models.ForeignKey(WorkingTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique=True,
                                      error_messages={'unique': 'An account with this email exist.',
                                                      'required': 'Please provide an email address.'})
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_substitute = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('is_active', 'last_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([
                     self.email_address,
                     self.last_name,
                     self.first_name,
                     self.org_title,
                     self.manager,
                     self.manager.email_address,
                     self.hire_date,
                     self.classification_title,
                     self.working_title,
                     self.email_address,
                     self.category,
                     self.is_substitute,
                     self.department
                     ])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in ['first_name', 'last_name']:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val.capitalize())
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

MIGRATION staff_manager.0003_auto_20180131_1756:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.7 on 2018-01-31 17:56
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('staff_manager', '0002_auto_20171127_2244'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('category_name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ClassificationTitle',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('classification_title_name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Department',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('department_name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='OrganizationTitle',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('organization_title_name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='WorkingTitle',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('working_title_name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='category',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.Category'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='classification_title',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.ClassificationTitle'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='department',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.Department'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='email_address',
            field=models.EmailField(error_messages={'required': 'Please provide an email address.', 'unique': 'An account with this email exist.'}, max_length=250, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='first_name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=150),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='hire_date',
            field=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='last_name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=150),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='manager',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.Employee'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='manager_email',
            field=models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='org_title',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.OrganizationTitle'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='working_title',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='staff_manager.WorkingTitle'),
        ),
    ]
```

TRACEBACK:

```
Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, csvimport, sessions, staff_manager
    Running migrations:
      Applying staff_manager.0003_auto_20180131_1756...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "test"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 684, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/www-root/envs/django_env_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "test"

(django_env_1) www-root@Server:~/envs/django_env_1/smrt$
^C
(django_env_1) www-root@Server:~/envs/django_env_1/smrt$ django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "test"django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "test"
```

Comment: Is your current database empty? Does your `models.py` contain a field with `default="test"` or something similar?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code from 
 the `staff_manager.0003_auto_20180131_1756` migration?

Comment: And the code for your models as well

Comment: Updated to include models, getting the migration now...

Comment: Okay,  I now have the model code for the staff_manager app, and the migration up in full.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue is likely related to [this open bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25012) in Django. You have some test data in one of the fields that you are now converting to a ForeignKey.

For instance, maybe `department` used to be a `CharField` and you added an employee who has "test" as their `department` value. Now you're trying to change `department` from a CharField to a ForeignKey. The issue is that Django is trying to convert the previous value "test" into a relational value (integer) for the ForeignKey.

I can think of a few good solutions:

- If this is just a test database, just reset your database and run the migration on a clean database
- If you need to migrate the existing data, figure out what field has the "test" value. Then try something similar to the solution given in the bug report:

```

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('documents', '0042_auto_19700101-0000'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE documents_document_tags ALTER tag_id TYPE varchar(32);'),
    ]
```

Comment: Great lead! Thanks for the response.  I'm not attached to the data at all.  What is the best way to reset a database in django?  I'm guessing I'll first go and drop the database in postgreSQL, but then do I need to delete the migrations for the apps too?

Comment: @unpaid-intern my preference is [reset_db from django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html)

Comment: Awesome. That did it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have the same issue on the development. This command works for me.

```
python manage.py flush
```

Make sure it removes all data from the database. Run this command, it will delete all data from the database and run migration again.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for providing the command. Cured my headache.

Answer (score 1):

In my case error was thith replace `IntegerField` to `TextField in file migartion

file migration:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.3 on 2020-12-03 11:19

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('adminPanel', '0028_auto_20201203_1117'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='myuser',
            name='balance',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='myuser',
            name='bot_admin_chat_id',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
    ]
```

I change `IntegerField` to `TextField` & python manage.py migrate

After that, I remove my column in models, makemigration & migrate
After that, I do thth my model that ever I want.

Comment: This worked for me but I didn't change any migrations, just removed the last one, then removed the field, migrated and added the modified field, after that migrations worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that works for me is changing the foreign key to a character field, Make migrations, migrate. Then change back the field to be a foreign key. This way, you will force a database alteration which is very important

Answer (score 0):

In my case @YPCrumble was correct and it was caused after I changed a field from a StreamField to a CharField.

The quickest solution I found was to open up my DB on a GUI (Postico in my case) and overwrite the values from JSON to the default value. This meant setting every existing fields values to 1, in my situation.

This let the migration run as intended, without issue.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing. Glad you are back in business.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your models file.

You made use of Charfield where there was Foreignkey expectation.

You can simply flush the database to empty it, then migrate again, it will work.

python manage.py flush

Then

python manage.py migrate