# How to change Django model with content in the database

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `CharField` that has a choices set, but I need to change the field to a `ForeignKey` field. I have made the changes but, when I make the migration, I got an error saying `django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "GRAND_TOURISM"`, that I realize means that the current content of the field doesn't match the new foreign reference constraint.

Is there any way I can instruct Django to change current values to Null when migrating?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548878/psycopg2-dataerror-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-test-getting-error-when

Comment: If `null` is acceptable, why not add a new `fk` field instead of modifying the existing one?